# St. Thomas Aquinas on the Worthy Reception of Holy Communion and the Forgiveness of Venial Sins?

Tags: catholicism, sin, communion, saint, thomas-aquinas

What did St. Thomas Aquinas (and/or perhaps, Augustine et al.) have to say regarding the worthy reception of Holy Communion and the forgiveness of venial sins?

Answer (score 1):

Thomas Aquinas claims that the reception of the Holy Eucharist forgives venial sins: [*Summa Theologica* III q. 79 a. 4 "Whether venial sins are forgiven through this sacrament?"](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/TP/TP079.html#TPQ79A4THEP1)

His statement on the worthy reception: [*Summa Theologica* III q. 80 a. 4 "Whether the sinner sins in receiving Christ's body sacramentally?"](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/TP/TP080.html#TPQ80A4THEP1)

I have located these answers by [posing the question to Thomas Aquinas Emulator](https://chat.openai.com/share/24318893-c1f0-46ee-bb5e-e982e734def8).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @agarza it would be good to add the info - or at least the references that you found - but please don't quote anything that came from genAI.